# Deploy spring boot war into weblogic 12.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a simple spring boot application (v 2.7.3) with JDK 8 and I want to deploy the war to Weblogic 12.2 but an error is showen:

```
Stack trace for message 149004 weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) 

Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

Comment: There is far too little information. Basically you dump a stacktrace on us and tell us it doesn't work. Please provide additional infromation (I expect there to be more information in the full stacktrace, show your config etc. ).

Comment: I followed this tutorial step by step: https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server

Comment: I tried to deploy a spring mvc application following this tutorial: https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server
But the same error was shown. Is there something wrong with my weblogic server ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by adding a web.xml file to the project.